# Does it ever make sense to calculate correlation for a single individual when they are the full population?

Tags: correlation, sample-size

Suppose I have a survey that I give to John. By giving this survey, I am only interested in John's answers and how he responds to the survey - he is therefore the true "population" (not looking to use him to generalize to a larger population)

John rates several individual questions and one overall question, many times under different conditions. I am interested in the relationship between each of the individual questions and the overall for ***John*** (again, not as a measure for the general population).

In this case, would it make sense to calculate the correlation between John's answers to question 1 (for example) with his answers to the "overall" question?

Sample size would likely not be very high, but since I'm interested in quantifying results only for that person (i.e. they are the population), would that matter?

Comment: It may be unhelpful to think of John as the population for this purpose: isn't the population *a hypothetical set of all possible responses he might make?*  If so, then you never have the full population; you can only sample from it.

Comment: @whuber but then what would the population size be in this case? For example, if he has 10 questions and an overall that he is rating from 1-10, which he does around 10 times so you can look at the relationship between each question and the overall.

Comment: The "population" doesn't have a size.  It isn't really meaningful to use a population metaphor here: a better one would be a *process* that can produce an arbitrarily large number of observations.

Comment: @whuber can you expand on how you would go about this?

Comment: I cannot, because your description is so vague.  As far as I can tell there's nothing special or different about this situation compared to any other situation where a process is sampled.  You might need to consider the possibility that serial correlation or trends should be incorporated in your model: that is, you might need to account for gradual changes in mood or knowledge.  Such studies are termed *longitudinal analyses* and often benefit from the use of random-effects models and methods.